# kubernetes cluster fails to start with minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kvm, rhel7, minikube

I was trying out `Kubernetes` using `minikube` in a `VM` host using `KVM` as `VM Driver`.But it looks like I cannot use KVM on a vm host as virtualization will not be enabled on a VM host.

```
 $ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
 0
```

`minikube start` is failing with the below error

```
$ minikube start --vm-driver=kvm
Starting local Kubernetes v1.8.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Downloading Minikube ISO
140.01 MB / 140.01 MB [============================================]    
100.00% 0s
E1108 02:38:25.792900   17062 start.go:150] Error starting host: Error  creating host: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: virError(Code=8, Domain=44, Message='invalid argument: could not find capabilities for domaintype=kvm ').
```

Any suggestions how to proceed on a `VM host`

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be to use `--vm-driver=none`. This will install all minikube binaries in host machine. While not all features are available, it should be enough for doing some testing.

Comment: Was there any special configuration options need to make minkube launch via this method besides `--vm-driver=none`.

Answer (score 0):

Links that would help

[Minikube install in Ubuntu vm_VT-X/AMD-v enabling to VM inside another VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294304/minikube-install-in-ubuntu-vm-vt-x-amd-v-enabling-to-vm-inside-another-vm)

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube#quickstart

Answer (score 0):

See info about enabling nested virtualization: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_enable_nested_virtualization_in_KVM

Answer (score 0):

open another terminal and check that swap is disabled `swapoff -a` then it will succeed