# Error Starting Minikube on Ubuntu VM VirutalBox

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I do have an Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox on Windows 10. If i follow the instructions to install Minikube I get a start error:

```
> minikube start &
[1] 4297
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ o   minikube v0.35.0 on linux (amd64)
>   Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2048MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
@   Downloading Minikube ISO ...
184.42 MB / 184.42 MB [============================================] 100.00% 
0s
!   Unable to start VM: create: precreate: VBoxManage not found. Make sure 
VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path
```

Does it mean i need to install VirtualBox in the Ubuntu VM too? Kind of VB inside VB..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to install Minikube on your host OS ([Windows](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/#windows)) and use the already installed Virtual box as a hypervisor provider.

If for any reason you want to launch it on Ubuntu VM, there are two options:

**I.** Minikube supports a --vm-driver=none option that runs the Kubernetes components on the host and not in a VM. Using this driver requires Docker and a Linux environment, but not a hypervisor. In this case you have to provide an address to you local API server

```
 `minikube start --vm-driver=none --apiserver-ips 127.0.0.1 --apiserver-name localhost`
```

And then go and edit ~/.kube/config, replacing the server IP that was 
     detected from the main network interface with "localhost". For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
   clusters:
     - cluster:
       certificate-authority-data:/home/asuh/.minikube/ca.crt
       server: https://localhost:8443
     name: minikube
```

**II.** Install VM Ware on Windows and run Ubuntu within installed Virtualbox
   and and enabled VT-X/AMD-v in outer VM.

---

Regarding the error you have at the moment:

> However now i get another error like: /usr/local/bin/minikube: cannot
>   execute binary file

Make sure you have installed a proper version of Minikube. For your Ubuntu VM it should be

```
curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 \
  && chmod +x minikube
```

Comment: many thanks. Can you please elaborate more on the configuration of the solution II ? What would be the difference to have VMWare?

Comment: @toto' Virtual Box does not support VT-X/AMD-v in nested virtualization while VMWare does

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use VM inside VM to run minikube. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43285922) answer. Try to run minikube with no vm drivers.

`minikube start --vm-driver=none`

I have read on [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) issues, but can not find it right now.

HTH

Comment: thanks. However now i get another error like:     /usr/local/bin/minikube: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: What is the reason behind installing minikube on VM?  Why can't you just install Minikube on your host OS (Windows)  and use already installed VirtualBox as a hypervisor provider?